# fetch_async and get_result ndb equivalent in Firestore

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-firestore

We are trying to migrate an application from Python 2.7 to Python 3.6 in Google Standard environment App engine. The Python 2.7 has NDB datastore, the python 3.6 environment has firestore. We are changing the database from NDB to Firestore.

We have a list of queries in NDB datastore that are mutually independent. They get triggered using fetch_async, we then collect the query results using get_result.

```
 mutually_exclusive_query1.fetch_async()
 mutually_exclusive_query2.fetch_async()
 mutually_exclusive_query3.fetch_async()
 mutually_exclusive_query4.fetch_async()
 mutually_exclusive_query5.fetch_async()

 mutually_exclusive_query1.get_result()
 mutually_exclusive_query2.get_result()
 mutually_exclusive_query3.get_result()
 mutually_exclusive_query4.get_result()
 mutually_exclusive_query5.get_result()
```

The goal is to make sure that each query is not sequenced one after another. The response time is dependent on the query that takes the most time to execute.

Is there an equivalent of this in Firestore (python 3.6)?

Answer (score 0):

You can still use NDB with python 3 (https://github.com/googleapis/python-ndb).  You can access your existing database from a non-App Engine Environment with Cloud NDB or using the Datastore APIs directly (https://googleapis.dev/python/datastore/latest/index.html).

Comment: We don't want to use NDB. We are migrating to Firestore.